# CSS position element before transition and transform

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I m trying to translate a div with css transform, and to apply to the movement a transition with css transition.

Is it possible to specify a "start" position to the element? I need to translate the element before the animation.

```
.mediaViewItem:nth-child(3) {
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.35, 1);
    transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0); translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```

in the code above I need the start to be translate3d(-200%, 0, 0) without animation, and then move from -200% to -100% with the transition.

Any idea?

Comment: Consider using [`animation`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) instead of `transition`?

Comment: tnak you! I managed to get it working with animation! that was the missing part!

Answer (score 0):

That is the initial position you set for the element, add a class using javascript
that it restores the element transforn to the normal position when you need to do the animation. Eg. add via js a class like:

```
.animated {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```